# Unsafe Cipher Mode warning in Google Play pre-launch report

Tags: android, encryption, azure-ad-msal

When uploading our app to Google Play, Google complaints about "Unsafe Cipher Mode" in "Pre-launch report", referencing this : `com.microsoft.identity.common.adal.internal.cache.StorageHelper->getKeyThumbPrint`

The reports points here: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10046138

So if I want to change the cipher method to the suggested value `AES/GCM/NoPadding` where do I do that in my MSAL approach, and do I need to do some tweaks on the server side handling the accessTokens or in Microsoft Azure setup ?

Comment: Sniffing around in Github I ran upon this: 
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1540
But I still don't know how to change it...